# assert date only against datetime result

Tags: assert, assertion, assertj

**API response**

```
{
  "lastModified": "2020-07-27T07:48:31.1208036Z"
}
```

**codes to verify date**

```
def date = new Date()
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
println sdf.format(date)
assert responseData.lastModified == sdf
```

****error** how can i just compare the date from "lastModified" ?**

```
   assert responseData.lastModified == sdf
           |            |            |  |
           |            |            |  java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f67a0200
           |            |            false
           |            2020-07-27T07:48:31.1208036Z
```

Answer (score 0):

The code sample is comparing a date with a SimpleDateFormat, this will always fail.
To compare date you can try AssertJ [isEqualTo(String)](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.16.1/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractDateAssert.html#isEqualTo(java.lang.String)) date assertion that takes a String representation of a date, example:

```java
assertThat(date).isEqualTo("2003-04-26T03:01:02.999");
```

Should the default supported date formats don't work for you, you can specify your own using [withDateFormat(String)](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.16.1/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractDateAssert.html#withDateFormat(java.lang.String)) like this:

```java
assertThat(date).withDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z")
                .isEqualTo("2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT");
```

Comment: i don't hardcord the value inside isEqualTo()

Comment: The example shows an hadrcoded value but I assume you will get a value by reading the lastModified field.

Comment: I don't get it still. I need to assert api response equal to sdf date. Both I defined and value already returned.